# The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, json, generic-list

I am trying to make a list of all items in the game `using System.Text.Json;`
I am very new to using .json files
I have tried doing this to test if it works:

```html
            List<Item> AllItems = new List<Item>();
            string json = File.ReadAllText("Items.json");
            AllItems = Deserialize<List<Item>>(json);
            WriteLine(AllItems[0].Name);
```

It doesnt let me Convert It into a list
This is the json file

```html
{
  "Item": [
    {
      "Weapon": [
        {
          "CritChance": 60,
          "HitChance": 80,
          "OGDamge": 15,
          "Damage": 15,
          "Damage_Type": "Physical",
          "Weapon_Type": "Fist",
          "Player": null,
          "APUsage": 4,
          "ID": 1,
          "Name": "Debug",
          "Value": 16,
          "Rarity": "Common",
          "Item_Type": "Weapon"
        },
        {
          "CritChance": 40,
          "HitChance": 70,
          "OGDamge": 15,
          "Damage": 15,
          "Damage_Type": "Electric",
          "Weapon_Type": "Bow",
          "Player": null,
          "APUsage": 5,
          "ID": 2,
          "Name": "Debug2",
          "Value": 15,
          "Rarity": "Common",
          "Item_Type": "Weapon"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me out :)

Comment: You'll need to create classes that represent that json structure. Check out [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/); you should at least have an `Item` and `Weapon` class. You will also have to decide what type of `Player` is going to be considering it's `null`.

Comment: Your List<Item> has to be a class with a property named "Item" which is a List<Item>

Comment: @zaggler how exactly would i do that lol, im not that advanced really

Comment: @PrinceJKB please see the link I posted, take your json and paste it in the editor, it will make the necessary classes based on that structure for you.

Comment: @zaggler should i paste this into visual studio or the json file

Comment: @PrinceJKB Are you talking about pasting the generated classes, if so, then that belongs in your project...

Comment: Your JSON cannot be serialized to a `List<>`. It contains a JSON object with a property called `Item`, which then contains a list.

Answer (score 16):

Your json file starts with curly braces that means you need parent class that contains list of Item named Item,
Or you just change your json file, starts with [ bracket
that means your main object is collection.

Answer (score 3):

The code below does not use the file you use but a string with (almost) the same contents. You need to declare classes for every item in your Json before you can deserialize with in this case NewtonSoft.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JsonDeserialize
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"
{
  'Items': [
    {
      'Weapons': [
        {
          'CritChance': 60,
          'HitChance': 80,
          'OGDamge': 15,
          'Damage': 15,
          'Damage_Type': 'Physical',
          'Weapon_Type': 'Fist',
          'Player': null,
          'APUsage': 4,
          'ID': 1,
          'Name': 'Debug',
          'Value': 16,
          'Rarity': 'Common',
          'Item_Type': 'Weapon'
        },
        {
          'CritChance': 40,
          'HitChance': 70,
          'OGDamge': 15,
          'Damage': 15,
          'Damage_Type': 'Electric',
          'Weapon_Type': 'Bow',
          'Player': null,
          'APUsage': 5,
          'ID': 2,
          'Name': 'Debug2',
          'Value': 15,
          'Rarity': 'Common',
          'Item_Type': 'Weapon'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}";

            var allItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllItems>(json);
            Console.WriteLine(allItems.Items[0].Weapons[0].Name);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class AllItems
    {
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public List<Weapon> Weapons { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weapon
    {
        public int CritChance { get; set; }
        public int HitChance { get; set; }
        public int OGDamge { get; set; }
        public int Damage { get; set; }
        public string Damage_Type { get; set; }
        public string Weapon_Type { get; set; }
        public string Player { get; set; }
        public int APUsage { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Rarity { get; set; }
        public string Item_Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What always helps me in these cases is using the 'dynamic' keyword like so:

```
        dynamic allItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

You can see what is deserialized using the 'locals'

[image]

Comment: i still have no idea what to do lol, i have an item class and weapon is a derived class from it

Comment: Can you see the hierarchy that is in the classes. The Allitems class has a list of Items. The Items have a list of Weapons. That is exactly what you declared in your Json. Try and read the code. What part of the code do you not understand? Don't just say I don't understand. Tell us what you don't understand.